# Recording a Screencast in XMonad

Tags: xmonad, screencast, recordmydesktop

I have been trying to record a screencast under xmonad, the problem is that it seems that both vokoscreen and record my desktop go a bit haywire when I try to tell them to record one window under xmonad.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SimpleScreenRecorder. I haven't tried yet the "Select Windows.." Button, but everything else seems promising. Good luck!